# Modify all fields in Postgres JSON field that match a condition

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have tens of thousands of records like so (Column name is 'details'):

```
"name": "ROSE", "role": "CHEW", "state": "Texas", "surname":
"OBAMA", "addresses": {"msisdn": {"0123456": {}}},
"facility_name": "Texas_Hospital", "receiver_role": "health care
worker", "personnel_code": "99999", "default_addr_type": "msisdn",
"preferred_language": "eng_NG", "uniqueid_field_name":
"personnel_code", "uniqueid_field_length": "5"
```

Now, I need to append the personnel code of each Health Care worker in Texas with an asterisk (ex, '99999*') so an external application will skip them.

I'm able to change them one after the other by doing this:

```
update identities_identity SET details =
JSONB_set(details,'{personnel_code}', to_jsonb('99999*'::text)) where
identities_identity.details->>'name' like 'ROSE';
```

but it very tedious as there are hundreds of them in the DB.

Is there a way to automate the process so it just adds an asterisk to each code that matches the expression (being every Health Care Worker in Texas)

[Column name is details]
[Database is identities_identity]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
UPDATE identities_identity
SET details = jsonb_set(
  details,
  '{personnel_code}',
  to_jsonb(details->>'personnel_code' || '*')
)
WHERE details->>'state' = 'Texas';
```

Comment: You are an absolute legend! Thanks :D